# WiFi adapter shows as "not ready", but internet is connected

Tags: networking, unity, internet

So, yeah, this is strange.

I installed Ubuntu through the mini.iso and installed the Unity desktop through the `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package and everything seemed normal until I noticed that the WiFi icon was greyed out. I think I'm connected through `wpa-supplicant` but I don't even know at this point.

Comment: While booted from the mini.iso, how exactly did you connect to the internet *before* installing all those desktop packages?

Comment: I connected via WiFi when prompted.

Comment: Have you rebooted since then? Or are you still using the same connection?

Comment: I have rebooted, yes, but I have not removed the connection, as I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Rebooting ends a network connection (and everything else). After a reboot, does the wifi automatically reconnect? Or do you take some action to initiate the new connection?

Comment: It automatically reconnects.

Comment: If you open a terminal and enter the command `nmcli`, do you get a list of network characteristics? Or a 'command not found' error? Or something else?

Comment: Ah, it shows my Intel wifi card as unavailable.

Comment: Look at `ip addr`. Which interface has your network connection?

Comment: Strange, it's loopback.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to run:

```
# sed -i -e 's/networkd/NetworkManager/g' /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Comment: Hi Heather! Just to confirm the `#` was not part of your command since it would comment out the entire line?

Comment: Nope, I was just indicating that I ran it as root.